# Вопрос по IP для DNS, почему для некоторых доменов сразу отдаётся IP?

Tags: dns

Есть домены, делегированные на свои DNS-сервера под PowerDNS.

При трассировке DNS-запроса обнаружилось, что корневые DNS сервера не отдают IP для моих DNS-серверов и запрос идёт по "стандартному" пути.

Вот трассировка моего домена:

```
Sending request to "f.root-servers.net" (192.5.5.241)
Received referral response - DNS servers for "su":
-> a.dns.ripn.net (193.232.128.6)
-> b.dns.ripn.net (194.85.252.62)
-> d.dns.ripn.net (194.190.124.17)
-> e.dns.ripn.net (193.232.142.17)
-> f.dns.ripn.net (193.232.156.17)

Sending request to "f.dns.ripn.net" (193.232.156.17)
Received referral response - DNS servers for "my-domain.su":
-> ns1.my-dns-server.ru (no IP address) <- вот тут проблема
-> ns2.my-dns-server.ru (no IP address) <- вот тут проблема
-> ns3.my-dns-server.ru (no IP address) <- вот тут проблема
-> ns4.my-dns-server.ru (no IP address) <- вот тут проблема

Attempting to resolve DNS server name "ns1.my-dns-server.ru"  (details not logged)
Resolved DNS server name "ns1.my-dns-server.ru" to IP address 123.123.123.123

Sending request to "ns1.my-dns-server.ru" (123.123.123.123)
Received authoritative (AA) response:
-> Answer: A-record for my-domain.su = 123.123.123.1
-> Answer: A-record for my-domain.su = 123.123.123.2
```

А вот трассировка случайного домена. Для всех проверенных доменов в зонах ru, su, com запрос идёт по схожему сценарию.

```
Sending request to "b.root-servers.net" (192.228.79.201)
Received referral response - DNS servers for "ru":
-> f.dns.ripn.net (193.232.156.17)
-> a.dns.ripn.net (193.232.128.6)
-> e.dns.ripn.net (193.232.142.17)
-> b.dns.ripn.net (194.85.252.62)
-> d.dns.ripn.net (194.190.124.17)

Sending request to "a.dns.ripn.net" (193.232.128.6)
Received referral response - DNS servers for "example.ru":
-> ns2.lpmotor.ru (88.198.134.150) <- вот как добиться такого?
-> ns1.lpmotor.ru (88.198.14.156)  <- вот как добиться такого?

Sending request to "ns1.lpmotor.ru" (88.198.14.156)
Received authoritative (AA) response:
-> Answer: A-record for example.ru = 185.165.123.167
```

Как видно, во втором запросе IP DNS-серверов уже видно на этапе запроса к корневому серверу.

Изначально такое поведение задумывалось для glue records, но я проверил множество доменов и ни у кого нет glue record во whois домена. Да и нашел несколько доменов, где почти каждый день ip dns-серверов меняют, они бы устали каждый раз обновлять glue записи.

Glue record - это запись у регистратора, когда помимо домена DNS-сервера указывается так же и его IP. В ответе IP-адреса добавляются в секцию ADDITIONAL

Скажите, пожалуйста, может кто-то знает почему корневые сервера к некоторым ответам добавляют IP, а к ответам о моих доменах нет?

Вопрос очень серьёзный, потому что этап

```
Attempting to resolve DNS server name "ns1.my-dns-server.ru"  (details not logged)
Resolved DNS server name "ns1.my-dns-server.ru" to IP address 123.123.123.123
```

Увеличивает время обработки запроса в два раза

Чуть не забыл. Домен моего DNS-сервера my-dns-server.ru делегирован на сторонний, платный, dns-сервис. А мои домены уже делегированы на my-dns-server.ru

Comment: 1. корневой сервер — это, например, `f.root-servers.net.`, а `f.dns.ripn.net.` — «никаким боком» к корневым серверам не относится. 2. по поводу наличия/отсутствия additional section см., например: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52136176/4827341

Comment: Естественно не относятся, но написание данного вопроса было сложным, потому что хотелось максимально упростить текст, для большего понимания. Изначальную формулировку "сервера, отвечающие за зону ru." решил исказить в угоду читаемости. Но, видимо, не помогло, раз даже Вы не осмыслили вопрос. По Вашей ссылке: No "Additional" section at all, because all nameservers are out of zone!, но сделав dig @e.dns.ripn.net bbccdd.ru ns - видно, что секция Additional присутствует

Comment: `dig @e.dns.ripn.net bbccdd.ru ns` - *видно, что секция Additional присутствует* — ip-адреса присутствуют потому, что `e.dns.ripn.net` обслуживает (в т.ч. и) зону `ru.`, в которой и располагаются доменные имена ns-ов `ns1.LPMOTOR.RU.` и `ns2.LPMOTOR.RU.`, и «знает» эти адреса.

Comment: сравните, например, вывод `$ dig @e.dns.ripn.net ns lis.ru.` и `$ dig @e.dns.ripn.net ns lis.su.` (данный ns обслуживает обе зоны — и `ru.` и `su.`)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, вот я дурак. Спасибо большое! Осталось понять больше деталей. Например, для `dig @e.dns.ripn.net amic.ru ns` показывает ip только сервера из их домена, а для `dig @e.dns.ripn.net kakvarim.ru ns` вообще не показывает. Но проверив много доменов, эти примеры скорее исключение и Ваше объяснение про _e.dns.ripn.net обслуживает (в т.ч. и) зону ru._ очень помогло. Спасибо! Примеры всех доменов взяты из открытых источников и я не имею к ним отношения.